# 403 Forbidden error after symfony 2 reinstall

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, capifony

I am building a web app on top of the symfony2 framework. Everything used to work fine until, due to some problems, i had to wipe the production symfony folder clean and reinstall everything inside the symfony project folder.
Now every request to the server returns a 403, `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Note: the server software is apache2 running on ubuntu.

I deployed using capifony, running `cap deploy:setup` and `cap deploy`.

Nothing changed in any apache config files or anything outside the root directory of the symfony project. The server root points to `symfonyRoot/current/web`, the .htaccess file in that directory looks as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**Edit:**

from the apache2.conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

from the virtual host config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/SymfonyRoot/current/web">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Options None
</Directory>
```

I am sure that it is just one simple thing that i am forgetting somewhere, but i can't figure out why the server is denying permission to any routes.

Comment: Check in your apache2.conf if you have AllowOverride On. This might explain why your .htacess is ignored

Comment: See the updated question. However, i would be very surprised if the reason is anywhere outside the symfonyroot folder, since it all worked perfectly fine before and that is the only folder i touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured out what was wrong:

`Options FollowSymLinks` was not turned on for the `/var/www/SymfonyRoot/current/web` folder.

just added `Options FollowSymLinks` to the .htaccess file and everything works like a charm again!

Comment: where did u add the option FollowSymLinks i have the same probleme  this is my htaccess <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>